# Share a method between 2 classes C#

Tags: c#, class, generics, methods

I have simplified what I have into this:

```
class A : SomeClassICantAccess
{
    IVIClass ivi = new IVIClass();

    public A()
    {
        string address = "1111";
        ivi.Initialize(address);
    }

    public void SendCommand(string cmd)
    {
        ivi.Send(cmd);
    }
}

class B : SomeClassICantAccess
{
    IVIClass ivi = new IVIClass();

    public B()
    {
        string address = "2222";
        ivi.Initialize(address);
    }

    public void SendCommand(string cmd)
    {
        ivi.Send(cmd);
    }
}

class Main()
{
    //I want my main to keep this format
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();

    a.SendCommand("commands");
    b.SendCommand("commands");
}
```

As you can see, class `A` and `B` have identical `SendCommand()` method, but since their `ivi`s are initialized with different address, the commands are sent to different instruments.

It seems wrong to have a same method copied-pasted in two different classes. But I really want my `Main()` to look like how it is right now - so that it will be clear whether the `SendCommand()` is refered to instrument A or instrument B.

How can I merge them?

Comment: Do you really need two classes at all? Couldn't you have a single class with two factory methods to create instances with different initial data? If not, you might want an abstract base class that both derive from.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Merge the two classes and instantiate two different `ivi`s inside the class? But then I would still need to have 2 sets of `SendCommand()` methods - one contains `ivi1.Send()`, the other contains `ivi2.Send()`

Comment: No, you'd have a single class, but you'd create different *instances* of the class. Basically the same sort of answer as un-lucky gave.

Comment: //I want my main to keep this format <- Whats the format youre referring to? The two classes? If you wanna keep the two classes for whatever reason (maybe this is just a half implementation and they do differ more than here, I would recommend Backs answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34305991/985798

Comment: I missed out inheritance in my code, sorry about that. Class A and B are actually inheriting from a class I can't access (a DLL reference). With that, how can I still create a base class and have A and B inherit from it?

Comment: This is a very basic OOD question. It can be solved with simple OO programming techniques like inheritance or preferably aggregation. Or one of the many patterns depending of the complexity of the whole scenario. At the end, it is quite opinion based and depends much on the whole context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is your actual scenario, there is no need for two class you can deal with `A` only:

Class definition for `A`:

```
class A()
{
    IVIClass ivi = new IVIClass();
    public A(string address)
    {        
        ivi.Initialize(address);
    }
    public void SendCommand(string cmd)
    {
        ivi.Send(cmd);
    }
}
```

How To Use:

```
class Main()
{   
    A a = new A("1111");//initialize  ivi with "1111"
    A b = new A("2222");//initialize  ivi with "2222"
    a.SendCommand("commands");
    b.SendCommand("commands");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a base interface, let's call it `ICommandSender` and an extension method that takes an instance of ICommandSender as it's source.

```
// Base interface
public interface ICommandSender
{
    // Shared definition
    IVIClass ivi;
}

public class A : SomeOtherClass, ICommandSender
{
    // A code here
}

public class B : SomeOtherClass, ICommandSender
{
    // B code here
}

// Extension Methods are held in a static class (think Façade Pattern)
public static class ExtMethods
{
    // Accept the source and cmd 
    // The this keyword indicates the target type.
    public static void SendCommand(this ICommandSender source, string cmd)
    {
        source.ivi.Send(cmd);
    }
}

// Main doesn't change at all.
class Main()
{
    //I want my main to keep this format
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();

    a.SendCommand("commands");
    b.SendCommand("commands");
}
```

Comment: Sorry I missed out something in my code, Class A and B are already inheriting from some class that I can't access (it's from an assembly reference).

Comment: Doesn't matter.  You can implement as many interfaces as you want with a class.

Comment: So current I have `Class A : SomeOtherClass`, how can I implement `ICommandSender`? Do I inherit `SomeOtherClass` in the interface?

Comment: You simply inherit SomeOtherClass and implement ICommandSender.  I've updated the answer code for the A and B class definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a base class?

```
class BaseClass
{
    IVIClass ivi = new IVIClass();
    public void SendCommand(string cmd)
    {
        ivi.Send(cmd);
    }
}

class A : BaseClass
{   
    public A()
    {
        string address = "1111";
        ivi.Initialize(address);
    }
}

class B : BaseClass
{   
    public B()
    {
        string address = "2222";
        ivi.Initialize(address);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I do this if currently Class A and B are already inheriting from Class C (And I can't do anything about Class C).

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class AbstractClass{

   protected String socket;

   public AbstractClass(String socket){
      this.socket = socket;
   }

   public virtual void SendCommand(String cmd){
     //dostuff
   }

}

class A : AbstractClass{
  public A(String socket):base(socket){
  }

  //you can ovverride the virtual method if need be. 
}
```

Same for Class B.